# Row in JTable error

Tags: java, jtable, row

I have defined a DefaultTableModel and I want to insert a new Row, but my code doesn't compile. What's the mistake? I can't see it!

```
window/Ventana.java:221: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable modelo
location: class window.Ventana
                modelo.newRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});
                ^
Note: window/Ventana.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

The main part of my code:

```
package window;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;




String[] nombre_columna = {"Name","Id","Won","Lost"};
Object[][] datos = {};
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(datos,nombre_columna);
JTable tabla = new JTable(modelo);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabla);
add(scrollPane);

modelo.addRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to format the code so it is readable?

Comment: You should post your real code not code with too much missing so we can't identify the problem.

Comment: The problem isn't newRow. I'm going to edit the code. The total code is too bigger to paste here.

Comment: you're very lucky some one could guess your problem, but next time, I advise  you to post classes with class declarations. Right now your code shows your imports and then goes right to some constructor or method code without a constructor or method body ... very confusing!

Comment: Yes, It's true. I will keep it in mind, thanks for everything!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that "modelo.newRow" is in a different medthod?  If so, then it's probably a scope issue and you need to declare modelo at the class level instead of at the method level.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any method like

```
modelo.newRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});
```

So compiler is giving error.

You should use the following

```
modelo.addRow(new Object[]{"","","",""});
```

`